# 95 Integra idle cutout troubleshooting

Tags: engine, stall, acura, integra

Starting was difficult and a failure finally forced a battery replacement, which remedied the difficult starts.   Before the battery was replaced, the engine was jump started and idled for 15 min with no problem.  Later in the afternoon the idle failure began. What is the first step to identifying why the engine is cutting out?

When at idle, the engine will cut out within 2-5 minutes.  When in gear, the tachometer will instantaneously spike 500-1500 RPM for no reason (the engine RPM does **not** spike, **only** the tach indicator spikes).  There may be a new whine / tone that was not present this morning.

I had a 240SX that had a similar problem (no tachometer spiking) and was resolved by replacing the O2 sensor with an OEM sensor